# Printing Structs inside Structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printf, typedef

I want to print a structure of structures. My code currently looks like this: (I haven't pasted it here, but Shelf is just a typedef of struct shelf).

```
struct shelf {
    struct book *books;
    struct shelf *next;
};

struct book {
    int text;
    int image;
    struct book *next;
};

Shelf create_shelf(void) {
    Shelf new_shelf = malloc(sizeof (struct shelf));
    new_shelf->next = NULL;
    new_shelf->books = NULL;
    return new_shelf;
}
```

I now want to print my shelves, the books inside them and each image and text in each of these books like this:

Output: , , ... and so on, where text1 and image1 refers to book1.

I've started to try to code this, but I cannot understand what is wrong with my print function below. How would I approach printing everything **while only allowing the input "Shelf shelf" as the argument in my function?**

```
void print_everything (Shelf shelf) {
    while (shelf != NULL) {
        printf("%d, %d", shelf->books->text, shelf->books->image);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make your `print_everything`  follow the `next` pointers until it reaches the end of the list. Right now it's an infinite loop when you pass it a non-null argument.

Comment: Does the above code even run?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Are you sure the text and image are supposed to be just numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Considering `Shelf` is typedef of `struct shelf *` and not `struct shelf`.

```
  void print_everything (Shelf shelf) {
        while (shelf != NULL) {
            printf("%d, %d", shelf->books->text, shelf->books->image);
            shelf = shelf -> next; // Add this line
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Oops, `sizeof(Shelf)` would just be the size of a pointer.

Comment: How about quotes around the format specifier string?

Comment: Considering _never_ to hide pointers in typedefs?

Comment: @PaulOgilviet My bad, I just copied the code and added the last line without checking the code.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I said that because his code wouldn't run if he didn't `typedef` it to `struct shelf *`